# Join two dataframes by the closest datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, left-join

I have two dataframes `df_A` and `df_B` where each has date, time and a value. An example below:

```
import pandas as pd
df_A = pd.DataFrame({
    'date_A': ["2021-02-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-02-02"],
    'time_A': ["22:00:00", "23:00:00", "00:00:00"],
    'val_A': [100, 200, 300]})

df_B = pd.DataFrame({
    'date_B': ["2021-02-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-02-02"],
    'time_B': ["22:01:12", "22:59:34", "23:00:17", "23:59:57", "00:00:11"],
    'val_B': [104, 203, 195, 296, 294]})
```

I need to join this dataframes but date and time never match. So I want a left join by the closest datetime from `df_B` to `df_A`. So the output should be:

```
df_out =  pd.DataFrame({
    'date_A': ["2021-02-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-02-02"],
    'time_A': ["22:00:00", "23:00:00", "00:00:00"],
    'val_A': [100, 200, 300],
    'date_B': ["2021-02-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-02-01"],
    'time_B': ["22:01:12", "23:00:17", "23:59:57"],
    'val_B': [104, 195, 296]})
```

[df_out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiMld.png)

[image: df_out]

Comment: FYI, in your example, you have `294` as the `val_B` value in `df_out`.  I think it should actually be `296`, given your raw data.

Comment: Exactly!! Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas has a handy `merge_asof()` function for these types of problems (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

It requires a single key to merge on, so you can create a single date-time column in each dataframe and perform the merge:

```
df_A['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A.date_A + " " + df_A.time_A)
df_B['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_B.date_B + " " + df_B.time_B)

# Sort the two dataframes by the new key, as required by merge_asof function
df_A.sort_values(by="date_time", inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
df_B.sort_values(by="date_time", inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

result_df = pd.merge_asof(df_A, df_B, on="date_time", direction="nearest")
```

Note the direction argument's value is "nearest" as you requested.  There are other values you can choose, like "backward" and "forward".

Comment: The docs say "Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key" so does that mean you should explicitly sort `df_A.date_time` and `df_B.date_time` here?

Comment: @tdy Yes, thanks, added that sort to the answer to make that step explicit.